# variable defined in prototype are shared accross objects?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have create object lik

```
e this
testObj.prototype = {
    cVar: 15,
    init: function(c){
        /*initialization code*/
        this.cVar = c;
    }
};

var a = new testObj(10);
var b = new testObj(20);
```

Now both object's cVar values is 20. Are they sharing the variable? How i can get seperate variable for each object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they're shared. For separate properties, define them inside the constructor:

```
function Ctor() {
    this.notShared = 1;
};

Ctor.prototype.shared = 2;
```

Comment: how to access this.notShared? inside prototype.init?

Comment: `this.notShared`, but you must call the constructor before calling `init`.

Comment: This example is slightly confusing. `var o1 = new Ctor(); var o2 = new Ctor(); o1.shared += 1; console.log("o1.shared = " + o1.shared + ", o2.shared = " + o2.shared);` gives `o1.shared = 3, o2.shared = 2`. I know this is obvious, but the **shared** sense of it doesn't come out through this example. It'd be better if the example demonstrated the shared state by using `Ctor.prototype.shared = {}`

Comment: @BharatKhatri makes a good point. If you modify the shared variable on one of the instantiated objects, then it becomes "unshared" on that object (as the variable has been re-assigned on it).