# nestet object instances

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with nested object and prototyping.
In following example I'm creating 2 instances of the object "o"

```
var o = function(){};

o.prototype = {
val : 1,
test : {
        val2 : 1
    }
};

var t1 = new o();
var t2 = new o();

t1.val = 5;
t2.val = 20;

t1.test.val2 = 5;
t2.test.val2 = 10;

console.log(t1.val) //5
console.log(t2.val) //20

console.log(t1.test.val2) //10
console.log(t2.test.val2) //10
```

My question is why t1.test.val2 === t2.test.val2, where t1 and t2 are different variables, 
shouldn't they be totally separate ??

how to fix that code to have all objects and variables inside separate ?

Comment: FYI: This question appears to be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022122/variable-defined-in-prototype-are-shared-accross-objects), but that other question is based on a faulty premise (i.e., the OP should not see the behavior he sees, unless he's doing something tremendously wrong in his actual code, not included in the question's incomplete code sample).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a new object, the prototype is copied, but objects in the prototype are *not deep copied*; they are copied *by reference*. Thus, each new `o` instance has a copied *reference* to the *exact same* member objects of the prototype.

Instead, make the `test` object in your constructor so each instance has its own copy:

```
var o = function(){
    this.test = {
        val2 : 1
    }
};

o.prototype = {
    val : 1   // this is fine, since primitive values aren't copied by reference
};
```

Comment: thanks, 
is there other way to achieve the same solution ?
but not insert code to constructor ?

Comment: @Cezary Code *must* go in the constructor if you don't want non-primitive properties of the prototype to be shared. If you really don't want to put code in your prototype for some reason, you could use only primitive (i.e., non-object) values in your prototype.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are modifying a property of shared object (i.e. the prototype). Your code is basically the same as:

```
var val = 1;
var test = {
    val2 : 1
};

var t1 = {
    val: val,
    test: test
};
var t1 = {
    val: val,
    test: test
};

t1.val = 5; // changing property
t2.val = 20; // changing property

t1.test.val2 = 5; // changing property of shared object
t2.test.val2 = 10; // changing property of shared object
```

To fix that simply don't use prototype, i.e.

```
var o = function(){
    this.val = 1;
    this.test = {
        val2 : 1
    };
    // test is no longer shared, exists per instance
};
```